# Why isn't this truthy?

Tags: ruby

`prop` gets assigned a value. That should then make any call to `test_it?` on this instance truthy. Instead, `test_it?` returns nil.  What am I doing wrong?

```
class ClassA
    attr_accessor :prop

  def test_it?
    @prop
  end

end

a = ClassA.new
a.prop = "test"
if puts a.test_it?
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, assuming you're using `ClassA.new` and not actually `Class.new`. Are you sure that your example is enough to produce what you're seeing? If so, which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Edited. I added the `if` to the last line. Should it return true? Instead, I get nil.

Comment: No, it shouldn't return `true`. As you can clearly see in the documentation, [`Kernel#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) returns `nil` which is *falsey*, ergo the `else` branch is executed, which doesn't exist and therefore evaluates to `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want the if statement to evaluate to true, you need to do

```
if a.test_it?
  # code to execute unless statement is false or nil
end
```

The `if` statement will evaluate to true if `@prop` is not false or nil. So if you assign `@prop` to be `test`, then the if statement is true, and the code inside the `if` is evaluated.

Answer (score 6):

```
if puts a.test_it?
```

Here, you are not using `a.test_it?` , but the return value of [`puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) as the condition, which is `nil`.